# Display mouse coordinates on JFrame in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

This code creates a Frame screen and generates a mouseEvent when the user clicks anywhere on Frame. However, I want the code to acquire cursor coordinates wherever the user clicks the mouse button, as opposed to acquiring merely the coordinates of the top-right corner of the JFrame. I am not sure how to accomplish this. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
   public class Hw2MouseEventController extends JFrame {
   public Hw2MouseEventController() {
        MouseClkd mouse = new MouseClkd();
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        add(mouse);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hw2MouseEventController frame = new Hw2MouseEventController();
        frame.setTitle("Mouse Event Controller");
        frame.setLocation(450, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(450, 450);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class MouseClkd extends JPanel {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public MouseClkd() {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    x = e.getX();
                    y = e.getY();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString("(" + x + "," + y + ")", 10, 10);
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines, especially [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Among other things, we need to know what your code *does* do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to display coordinates at clicked place when user clicks the mouse.

That is what is happening. You added the MouseListener to the panel, so you get the mouse click relative to the panel.

If you want the mouse click relative to the frame, then you need to add the MouseListener to the frame.

Or maybe you just need to change:

```
//g.drawString("(" + x + "," + y + ")", 10, 10);
g.drawString("(" + x + "," + y + ")", x, y);
```

Comment: I tried all of them but the result has not changed. @camickr

Comment: Works fine for me. That is I get text displayed where I click the mouse and the text displays the value of the mouse point. I guess I don't understand your explanation of the problem. Tell us what you see and what you expect to see.

Comment: I ll try again your solution . I think you've got right. That is I get text displayed where I click the mouse and the text displays the value of the mouse point. That's like my question. Can you write here your code pls. @camickr